# Dynamic loading Emscripten modules from Electron

Tags: webpack, plugins, electron, emscripten

I have a C library that I compiled with Emscripten into a group of ".js", "worker.js", and ".wasm" files. This library is LGPL licensed. The main project for which this is used is closed source. Therefore I need the Emscripten module's files to be outside of electron's ".asar" file to allow the user to easily replace the LGPL licensed library. I believe this is also relevant for javascript plug-ins which use Emscripten compiled modules.

(All paths are on Windows.)

Using the `extraResource` option for electron forge, I got the three files to be outside of the ".asar". So I have

```
resources
|-- app.asar
|-- the-library.js
|-- the-library.wasm
`-- the-library.worker.js
```

I'm trying to dynamically load the ".js" file from the render process using

```js
global.require(path.join(absPathToResources, "the-library.js"))
```

This finds the "the-library.js" file, which I can tell be placing `console.log` lines into the file. The problem is that at some point I get the following error, and the wasm module does not work.

```
the-library.wasm:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

This shows up in the electron console, and when I hover over "the-library.wasm" I see a path like

```
[abs path to my app]/resources/app.asar/.webpack/renderer/main_window/the-library.wasm
```

However this file isn't at that path. It's at `[abs path to my app]/resources/the-library.wasm`. How do I make this work?